# Border Problems

Tags: html, css, web, edx

```
$https://jsbin.com/huqukopixe/edit?html,output
```

Hello guys , this is a edX homework for practice. In the code you will see a border on the banner. This border should not be there. I was trying to make a border to use it emphasizing on the social media account png's. But unfortunately I could not make to make it's length smaller. Andy advice?

Thank you alredy.

Answer (score 0):

I found that your `#media` has a `border-style: solid`, if you remove it the white border is gone, and if you remove `padding-left: 1000px` you will also see the social media icons.

[See this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsb1r.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's being caused by `border-style` on the `#media` selector. Adjust your CSS.

Change

```
#media {
    padding-left: 1000px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

to

```
#media {
    padding-left: 1000px;
    border-color: white;
    position: relative;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/haxaluweme/1/edit?html,output

And if you want to keep the white border but only at the social media icons:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--        meta parts-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta lang="en">
  <meta name="keywords" content="recipe, content, webdesign, edx">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" , initial-scale=1.0p>
  <meta name="author" content="Berkay MAKAS">
  <title>Recipe Project Module-2 by Berkay Makas</title>
  <style>
    /*         Css Parts. "Double Background color failure with text combination   */
    
    .textAll {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    
    #headerone {
      font-size: 70px;
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      border: 3px solid black;
    }
    
    #copy {
      background-image: url(https://www.freewebheaders.com/wordpress/wp-content/gallery/music/colorful-fantasy-piano-keyboard-keys-web-header.jpg);
      color: white;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
    
    h3 {
      color: crimson;
      font-style: oblique;
    }
    
    h4 {
      color: crimson;
    }
    
    #media {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      border-style: solid;
      width: 200px;
      border-color: white;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #header #copy {
      height: 119px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<!--        End of CSS-->

<body class="textAll">

  <header role="banner">

  </header>

  <!-- Header Part-->
  <div id="header">
    <div id="copy">
      <p><b>Designed by Berkay Makas®</b></p>
      <!--                Social Media -->
      <div id="media">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/brkymakas/" rel="author"><img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/instagram/instagram_PNG10.png" alt="Instagram Logo" width="50" height="50"></a>
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/berkay-makas-55014b126/?ppe=1" rel="author"><img src="http://www.imagespng.com/Data/Logo/Linkedin-Picture-180x180.png" width="55" height="55"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1 id="headerone"><i>Recipes for lunch!</i></h1>
    <nav>
      <ul style="display: inline;"><a href="#firstone" style="text-decoration: none; padding: .2em 1em;">Chicken with Sourdough-Mushroom Stuffing</a></ul>
      <ul style="display: inline"><a href="#secondone" style="text-decoration: none; padding: .2em 1em;">Blueberry-Sour Cream Dessert</a></ul>
      <ul style="display: inline"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; padding: .2em 1em;">Main Page</a></ul>
    </nav>
    <hr>
    <details>
      <summary>READ ME!!! </summary>
      <p>A brand new recipe paper per day to help you in order to overcome your thoughts on <b>"What the hell I am going to fo this day !</b>"</p>
    </details>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <!--        End of the header part-->

  <!--Recipes Part -->
  <article>
    <header id="firstone">
      <!--                First Recipe-->
      <h3>Chicken with Sourdough-Mushroom Stuffing</h3>
      <h4>Ingridients</h4>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Lemon Peel</td>
          <td>2 tablespoons</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sage</td>
          <td>1 Tablespoon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Salt</td>
          <td>1 tablespoon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Grounded black pepper</td>
          <td>1 1/2 teaspoons</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Small chicken</td>
          <td>8(5 pounds)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Butter</td>
          <td>1/4 cups</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mushrooms</td>
          <td>4 cups</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garlic</td>
          <td>2 cloves</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Baguette</td>
          <td>10oz</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Shredded carrot</td>
          <td>1 cup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Chicken broth</td>
          <td>1 cup</td>
          <tr>
            <td>Chopped wallnuts</td>
            <td>1/4 cup</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Italian parsley</td>
            <td>3 tablespoons</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
    </header>
    <section>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://images.meredith.com/bhg/images/recipe/ss_R064439.jpg" height="250px" weight="250px" alt="Original photo of the food" style="border-style: solid;">
        <figcaption>Fig 1. The image of the food.</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <footer>
        <h4>Directions</h4>
        <p> 1. Line a 5-1/2- to 6-quart slow cooker with a disposable cooker liner. Lightly coat liner with cooking spray; set aside. Reserve 1 teaspoon of the lemon peel. In a small bowl combine remaining lemon peel, sage, seasoned salt and pepper. Remove
          3/4 of the mixture and rub onto chicken legs. Place chicken in slow cooker.<br> 2. Meanwhile, melt butter in a skillet; add mushrooms and garlic. Cook and stir 3 to 5 minutes or until just tender. Stir in remaining sage mixture. Transfer mushroom
          mixture to a large bowl. Add bread cubes, and shredded carrot. Drizzle with chicken broth, tossing gently.<br> 3. Lightly pack stuffing on top of chicken. Cover and cook on high-heat setting for 4 to 5 hours.<br> 4. Transfer stuffing and chicken
          to a platter.<br> 5. In a bowl combine reserved lemon peel, walnuts, and parsley; sprinkle over chicken. Makes 8 servings.</p>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </article>
  <!--        End of first recipe <article> -->
  <hr>
  <!--        HR lining to design.-->
  <article>
    <!--            Header Part-->
    <header id="secondone">
      <h3>Blueberry-Sour Cream Dessert</h3>
      <h4>Ingredients</h4>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Dessert Crust</td>
          <td>1 recipe</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Fresh or frozen blueberries</td>
          <td>3 cups</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sugar</td>
          <td>1/3 cup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Tapioka</td>
          <td>3 tablespoons</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Water</td>
          <td>1/4 cup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ground Cinnamon</td>
          <td>1 teaspoon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lemon Peel</td>
          <td>1 teaspoon</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ground Nutmeg</td>
          <td>1/4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Egg yolks</td>
          <td>3 units</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sugar</td>
          <td>1/2 cup</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vanilla</td>
          <td>1 teaspoon</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </header>
    <!--            Section part-->
    <section>
      <figure>
        <img src="http://images.meredith.com/content/dam/bhg/Images/recipe/33/R090601.jpg.rendition.largest.jpg" alt="Blueberry cheesecake" height="250px" weight="250px" style="border-style: solid;">
        <figcaption>Fig 1. The image of the food.</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <footer>
        <h4>Directions</h4>
        <p>
          1. Prepare and bake Dessert Crust. Reduce oven temperature to 350 degrees F. In a medium saucepan, combine 3 cups blueberries, the 1/3 cup sugar, the tapioca, water, cinnamon, lemon peel, and nutmeg. Let stand for 15 minutes. Cook and stir mixture over
          medium heat until blueberries become juicy and mixture is bubbly. Turn into partially baked Dessert Crust.<br> 2. In a medium mixing bowl, combine sour cream, egg yolks, the 1/2 cup sugar, and the vanilla. Pour evenly over blueberry
          mixture.<br> 3. Bake about 50 minutes or until sour cream layer is set when gently shaken. Cool in pan on a wire rack for 1 hour. With a sharp knife, loosen crust from side of pan; remove side. Cover and chill overnight before serving.<br> 4.
          To serve, if desired, garnish with additional blueberries. Makes 12 to 16 slices.</p>

      </footer>
    </section>
  </article>
  <hr>
  <footer>
    <nav>
      <ul style="display: inline;"><a href="#firstone" style="text-decoration: none; padding: .2em 1em;">Chicken with Sourdough-Mushroom Stuffing</a></ul>
      <ul style="display: inline"><a href="#secondone" style="text-decoration: none; padding: .2em 1em;">Blueberry-Sour Cream Dessert</a></ul>
      <ul style="display: inline"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; padding: .2em 1em;">Main Page</a></ul>
    </nav>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```